Webscraping link
I'm web scraping job postings. For many websites they directly contain the 'a' tag with an 'href' attribute with the link to the exact posting that I can pull out by using a format like:
link = job.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
link = link.get_attribute('href')
I am using Selenium and specifically for ADP websites that contain the job postings I am lost on how to get the link for the specific job posting as it does not contain the href.
It can scrape other information and here is an example for scraping a company Metrea.4
https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid=39bc5efc-a576-4a4d-83eb-32e95d4e96c8&ccId=19000101_000001&lang=en_US&selectedMenuKey=CurrentOpenings
Here I can get information, but not the link.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def scrape_metrea():
    # Setup chrome options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Ensure GUI is off
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

    # Set up the Chrome webdriver service
    webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    # Start the browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

    # Open the webpage
    driver.get('https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid=39bc5efc-a576-4a4d-83eb-32e95d4e96c8&ccId=19000101_000001&lang=en_US&selectedMenuKey=CurrentOpenings')

    # Set implicit wait
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)  # Wait up to 10 seconds for elements to be found

    try:

        # Get the dynamic content
        job_listings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'current-openings-item')




        jobs_list = []


        for job in job_listings:
            location = ''
            job_info = {}
            title = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-opening-title').text
        

            location = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label.current-opening-location-item').text
            

            date = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-opening-post-date').text
        

            job_info['Company'] = 'Metrea'
            job_info['Job Title'] = title
            job_info['Job Link'] = None
            job_info['Location'] = location
            job_info['Date Posted'] = date
            job_info['ID'] = None
            job_info['Category'] = None
            job_info['Job Type'] = None

            jobs_list.append(job_info)


            #NO LINK CANT FIND OUT HOW TO PULL
    except:
        jobs_list = []
        message = {}
        message['Message'] = 'Error Scraping Company Metrea'
        jobs_list.append(message)
        print('Error scraping metrea')



    print('scraping Metrea')



    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
    return jobs_list

I've been trying to use the attribute but it does not contain this attribute so I'm confused, and I was also thinking about going thru and clicking each one and then getting the link but I'm a little lost if there is a better way to get the links as they're not visible.

"and I was also thinking about going thru and clicking each one and then getting the link" - That could indeed end up being the approach to take.  Web scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering, and some functionality is not easy to reverse-engineer.  There's no rule that says all navigation must be performed by simple <a href="..."> elements.  The target website could be doing anything they like.  For example, they could have click handlers on elements styled to look like links.

Did you use ChatGPT or another IA to generate the code in question?

How would you do it through the process of clicking each one and getting the link because I am trying but lost with the code as it keeps producing errors.

It is much faster/easier to get the data by scraping the site's api.
Here's code to get all the jobs, and their details if needed without selenium:

import requests

def get_job_requisitions(cid):
    params = {
        'cid': cid,
        '$skip': 1, # starting index (1 based)
        '$top': 20  # the max number the api will return
    }

    result = []
    while True:
        url = f'https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/careercenter/public/events/staffing/v1/job-requisitions'
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        data = response.json()
        jobs = data.get('jobRequisitions', [])
        result.extend(jobs)
        params['$skip'] += len(jobs)

        if len(result) >= data['meta']['totalNumber']:
            break

    return result


def get_job_details(item_id, cid):
    url = 'https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/careercenter/public/events/staffing/v1/job-requisitions/{job_id}?cid={cid}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()


cid = '39bc5efc-a576-4a4d-83eb-32e95d4e96c8'

all_jobs = get_job_requisitions(cid)
# example of getting the details of the first job:
item_id = all_jobs[0]['itemID']
details = get_job_details(item_id, cid)


I am not sure where cid comes from as I can't navigate to any other page on that site, it could be constant, but if it expires/changes, you could add a way to auto fetch it.
and if you want the same dict structure as your code:
job_list = [{
    "Company": "Metrea",
    "Job Title": job['requisitionTitle'],
    "Job Link": f"https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid={cid}&jobId={job['itemID']}",
    "Location": [loc['nameCode']['shortName'] for loc in job['requisitionLocations']],
    "Date Posted": job['postDate'],
    "ID": job['itemID'], # or `clientRequisitionID`?
    "Category": None, # not sure what this refers to
    "Job Type": job['workLevelCode']['shortName']
} for job in all_jobs] 


Try something like this:
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
    options=options
)

driver.get('https://workforcenow.adp.com/mascsr/default/mdf/recruitment/recruitment.html?cid=39bc5efc-a576-4a4d-83eb-32e95d4e96c8&ccId=19000101_000001&lang=en_US&selectedMenuKey=CurrentOpenings')

jobs_list = []

# Wait for job listings to show.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".current-openings-item"))
)
# Get all job listings.
job_listings = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".current-openings-item")

for job in job_listings:
    title = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-opening-title').text
    location = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label.current-opening-location-item').text
    date = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-opening-post-date').text

    jobs_list.append({
        "Company": "Metrea",
        "Job Title": title,
        "Job Link": None,
        "Location": location,
        "Date Posted": date,
        "ID": None,
        "Category": None,
        "Job Type": None
    })

driver.quit()

print(json.dumps(jobs_list, indent=2))

The key is to wait for the content to be visible on the page before you start trying to scrape anything.
 I prefer to run Selenium in a Docker container and connect as a remote webdriver. You can revert the call of webdriver.Remote() to webdriver.Chrome().
Output from script (first two elements):
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    "Company": "Metrea",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    "Job Title": "Commercial Associate",                                                                                                                                                                                                
    "Job Link": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "Location": "MAM HQ, Washington, DC, US",                                                                                                                                                                                           
    "Date Posted": "Yesterday",                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "ID": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "Category": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "Job Type": null                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    "Company": "Metrea",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    "Job Title": "Accounts Payable Administrator",                                                                                                                                                                                      
    "Job Link": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "Location": "Oklahoma, Bethany, OK, US",                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "Date Posted": "Yesterday",                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "ID": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "Category": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "Job Type": null                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }
]

There is no actual "job link". The details of each job are rendered into the same page when clicked on. You'll notice that your browser doesn't go to a separate URL when you click on a specific job. It will be best to retrieve these data using the API. See answer from @GTK.

Thank you, this is a similar way to scrape but I can already get the information such as Company, Job Title, Date, and Location. I'm not able to get the Job Link which is what I'm stuck on.
